# Can I update different documents in a single query in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update different documents in MongoDB with just a single query.
My existing Database collection looks like:

```
[ { "_id":"1", "name": null, "Age": null }, { "_id":"2", "name":null, "Age":null}, { "_id":"3", "name":null, "Age": null } ]
```

I have the following JSON:

```
[ { "_id":"1", "name":"Arav", "Age":"25" }, { "_id":"2", "name":"Mohan", "Age":"64" }, { "_id":"3", "name":"Nishant", "Age":"23" } ]
```

I want to know if its possible to update all the existing 3 documents with the respective data from above JSON with a single query. Something like:

```
db.products.insert( [ { "_id":"1", "name":"Arav", "Age":"25" }, { "_id":"2", "name":"Mohan", "Age":"64" }, { "_id":"3", "name":"Nishant", "Age":"23" } ] )
```

The problem is that it returns duplicate error and doesn't update the document if already existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`bulkWrite`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) operation

Suppose you have this JSON needs to be updated

```
const array = [
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Arav",
    "Age": "25"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Mohan",
    "Age": "64"
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "Nishant",
    "Age": "23"
  }
]
```

Now with the  [**`bulkWrite`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) query

```
Model.bulkWrite(
  array.map((data) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: data._id },
        update: { $set: { name: data.name, Age: data.age } }
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert 3 or more documents using one single query using **insertMany** instead of just **insert** as shown below -

db.products.insertMany( [ { "_id":"1", "name":"Arav", "Age":"25" }, { "_id":"2", "name":"Mohan", "Age":"64" }, { "_id":"3", "name":"Nishant", "Age":"23" } ] ).

**insertMany** returns a document containing:
 - A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was disabled.
 - An array of _id for each successfully inserted documents id